# How to Solve this " TypeError: read() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' "

Tags: python-3.x, rest, flask

I am using Flask to create a REST api to get all books stored in MSSQL database. When i simply run this code and print data in console it's working great. But when i run as a Flask API and try to get all data in postman, it's showing this error:

Complete Trace Back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Users\raj.pandey\Desktop\Flask_API\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
        return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
      File "C:\Users\raj.pandey\Desktop\Flask_API\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
        response = self.handle_exception(e)
      File "C:\Users\raj.pandey\Desktop\Flask_API\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "C:\Users\raj.pandey\Desktop\Flask_API\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
        raise value
      File "C:\Users\raj.pandey\Desktop\Flask_API\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
        response = self.full_dispatch_request()
      File "C:\Users\raj.pandey\Desktop\Flask_API\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
      File "C:\Users\raj.pandey\Desktop\Flask_API\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "C:\Users\raj.pandey\Desktop\Flask_API\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
        raise value
      File "C:\Users\raj.pandey\Desktop\Flask_API\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.dispatch_request()
      File "C:\Users\raj.pandey\Desktop\Flask_API\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
        return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
    TypeError: read() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
    127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2019 17:38:21] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\raj.pandey\Desktop\Flask_API\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
        return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
      File "C:\Users\raj.pandey\Desktop\Flask_API\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
        response = self.handle_exception(e)
      File "C:\Users\raj.pandey\Desktop\Flask_API\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "C:\Users\raj.pandey\Desktop\Flask_API\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
        raise value
      File "C:\Users\raj.pandey\Desktop\Flask_API\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
        response = self.full_dispatch_request()
      File "C:\Users\raj.pandey\Desktop\Flask_API\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
      File "C:\Users\raj.pandey\Desktop\Flask_API\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "C:\Users\raj.pandey\Desktop\Flask_API\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
        raise value
      File "C:\Users\raj.pandey\Desktop\Flask_API\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.dispatch_request()
      File "C:\Users\raj.pandey\Desktop\Flask_API\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
        return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
    TypeError: home() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Here's my code that is getting error:

```
class MssqlConnection:
    def __init__(self):
        credentials = Credentials()
        self.driver = credentials.driver
        self.host = credentials.host
        self.database = credentials.database
        self.table = credentials.table
        self.user = credentials.user
        self.password = credentials.password

    @app.route('/books')
    def read(self):
        query = "Select id, name, price, isbn from dbo." + self.table
        cursor.execute(query)
        for row in cursor:
            data = {
                'id': row.id,
                'name': row.name,
                'price': row.price,
                'isbn': row.isbn
            }
            # print(data)
            return jsonify(data)
```

I have checked it, but still can't understand what's the problem.

Comment: could you please add the complete Traceback?

Comment: yeah sure, wait a sec

Comment: why are you passing "self" argument to `def read()`? same for `home()` ...

Comment: self.table for this. in class after initialization every def gets self. and without it i can't access "self.variable"

Comment: could you send me your mail id sir, because I can't put that much code here? so I will send you my codes on that.

Comment: Done Sending Sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your endpoint function is not (or even should not) in a class probably. Just remove the `self` argument from `def read(self):` line and you will be fine. You should use "self" as an argument when you code in a class scope. You are not in a class scope. So the solution is `def read():`.

In Flask, only if you put a parameter in your url like `app.route('/books/<somevariable>')` you should pass `somevariable` to the endpoint function as an argument and write `def myfunction(somevariable):`

You can read the docs about that:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#variable-rules

Comment: by removing `self` from the `read()` method, the class variable `table` isn't accessible anymore

Comment: joey sir is right, and def read is in a class scope I haven't placed full code here because it's very lengthy.

Comment: But flask thinks "self" is a variable in url. You may use a global variable or create a service object and reach your data from there.